# Android Class crashes, not sure why

Tags: android, database, android-listview, listactivity

i am trying to create a class that will show the contents of a database and i have been using a [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) to find out the method of doing this. after doing the tutorial i thought i had a method f showing the contents of the database.

here is the class that will not work:

```
public class WorkoutProgress extends ListActivity {
private DataBaseHelper datasource;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progress);

    datasource = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    datasource.open();
    fillData();
    datasource.close();
}
 private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = datasource.getAllTitles();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_TITLE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

}
```

ok sorry i forgot to clarify a couple of things . one this classs will not open and instead crashes the application. the logcat for this class is here

> 04-03 14:31:25.556: ERROR/Database(14884): Failure 1 (near "tableacts": syntax error) on 0x2c2a00 when preparing 'create tableacts (id2integer primary key autoincrement, datetext not null,steps text not null, calories text not null);'.
>   04-03 14:31:25.556: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14884): Shutting down VM
>   04-03 14:31:25.556: WARN/dalvikvm(14884): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.b00348312.workout/com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutProgress}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableacts": syntax error: create tableacts (id2integer primary key autoincrement, datetext not null,steps text not null, calories text not null);
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableacts": syntax error: create tableacts (id2integer primary key autoincrement, datetext not null,steps text not null, calories text not null);
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1817)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at com.b00348312.workout.DataBaseHelper$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DataBaseHelper.java:60)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at com.b00348312.workout.DataBaseHelper.open(DataBaseHelper.java:78)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutProgress.onCreate(WorkoutProgress.java:25)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
>   04-03 14:31:25.566: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14884):     ... 11 more

Comment: Please tell us what isn't working. The best thing is to find the stacktrace of the exception in Logcat and post it here.

Comment: your create statement seems to go wrong?

Comment: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableacts": syntax error: create tableacts (id2integer primary key autoincrement, datetext not null,steps text not null, calories text not null);" : maybe you have a syntax error in your SQL query?

Comment: that is referring to a second table i have setup in my DataBaseHelper class which is not accessed in this class. though to check i will take out all statements that deal with the second table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave some spaces in the string where you declare the database creation string(probably in the `onCreate` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`):

***id2integer** primary key autoincrement, **datetext** not null,steps text not null, calories text not null*

Check the String above and put some spaces after `id2` and `date`(the first and second column of the database table).